# vuejs limit request to first 10 items

Tags: vue.js

I am making async promise that supposed to map in vuejs. I simply need to limit the request to the first 10 items...just a way to limit so it doesnt go through all results. The method i want to limit is getCodeLinkage2

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  box:[],
  Modules:[],
  
  },
  mounted:function(){
 getCodeLinkage2();
  },
  methods: {
    async getCodeLinkage2() {

        const data = await Promise.all(this.Modules.map(Modules => this.request('GET', `https://example.com/${Modules.Identifier}/content/voc`)));
     
        data.forEach(item => {
alert("data");
          this.box.push(item);
        });
        console.log(this.box);
      },

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

<ul>
<li v-for="mod in Modules">
        {{ mod.Code}}<br>
        {{ mod.Identifier}}
 </li>
    
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [filter out](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the first 10 items before requesting the data. `i` in this case is the index, we only look at items in the `Modules` array that have an index in the array smaller than our cutoff.

```js
const cutoff = 10
const data = await Promise.all(
  this.Modules
    .filter((_,i) => i < cutoff)
    .map(Modules => this.request('GET', `https://example.com/${Modules.Identifier}/content/voc`)));
```